# Prove $\dim(V) \leq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

> Consider $V$ a vector space over a field $K$. Consider a linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $T^2 = T$. Suppose $V$ is a cyclic $K[x]$-module. Prove that $\dim(V) \leq 2$.

I know that the vector space $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $k[x]/a_i(x)$ for different $i$, but I don't know how it relates to the dimension of $V$.

Thanks.

Comment: The dimension of $K[x](a_i(x))$ is equal to the degree of $a_i(x)$, so the dimension of $V$ is equal to the sums of the degrees of the $a_i(x)$. Note that since $V$ is cyclic as a $K[x]$-module, there is only one direct summand. So $V \cong K[x]/(a(x))$, where $a(x)$ is ...

Comment: Not true unless you say that $V$ is a $K[T]$-module (i.e., $x$ acts on $V$ as $T$).  For example, $T=\text{id}_V$ and $V=K[x]/\left(x^3\,K[x]\right)$ satisfy the conditions, but $\dim_K(V)=3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ is a cyclic module is equivalent to saying that there exists $x\in V$ such that $\{x, T^n(x), n\in N\}$ generates $V$, this implies that $\{x,T(x)\}$ generates $V$ since $T^2=T$. Thus $V$ has a family of generators of cardinal 2 and henceforth, $dim(V)\leq 2$.